# Problem installing LESS for Ruby on Rails - script/plugin: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, less

I am trying to install LESS in a Ruby on Rails project. I am able to run the gem successfully, but when I try to install the plugin for LESS, I get an error. Here's what shows in the terminal:

```
MacBook:benji jesse$ sudo gem install less
Successfully installed less-1.2.21
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for less-1.2.21...
Installing RDoc documentation for less-1.2.21...
MacBook:benji jesse$ sudo script/plugin install git://github.com/cloudhead/more.git
sudo: script/plugin: command not found
```

I am a .NET developer trying to learn Ruby on Rails (on a Mac), so I am new to all this stuff.

My question's are:

- Is the script/plugin command a standard command?

  - What does it do?
  - Where can I learn more about this command?
- Why does it say command
  can't be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the script/plugin command a standard command?

It is in rails 2, it has changed in rails 3:

```
rails plugin
# or
script/rails plugin
```

> What does it do?

installs the given plugin into the `RAILS_ROOT/vendor/plugin`, but you should look if there is a gem version of the plugin, than you can add a gem dependency to this gem.

> Where can I learn more about this command?

run the command without any parameters

> Why does it say command can't be found?

try `ls script/` and see if the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be in the application directory. Say you created your rails app in the folder development/rails_app. You must execute the `script/plugin` command from there (and you don't need super user permissions for that):

```
cd development/rails_app
script/plugin install git://github.com/cloudhead/more.git
```

The plugin installation will apply only to the current rails application (in this case, `rails_app`). So if you create another application, you must run the `script/plugin` command again.